# Dynamic date query in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, mdx, powerquery

I'm fairly new to power pivot / query / BI so please excuse my lack of understanding.

**Summary of what I'm doing**

- I have access to an OLAP cube which I am choosing to connect to via Power Pivot Data Model in Excel.
- In the Table Import Wizard, I am able to produce what I need from the cube and develop in the Power Model using fixed date ranges. However, this requires me to come back in and alter the date ranges for a number of reasons.
- I now want to limit my data dynamically based on a date filter.
- I want to do this in the query to limit my model size.
- I am working in the "Table Import Wizard" shown below
  [Snapshot of where I am working, note filter expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBf63.png)

**Question:**
Am I correct that to achieve this I write an MDX expression? If I add the [Received Date.Day] as a dimension, and change the operator to MDX, it is my understanding I can write an expression to dynamically filter the dataset? When the user refreshes the query they will only get that last 91 days of data based on the received date.

Essentially something like this (excuse my syntax as I have no idea what is required in this platform so I am just relating it to an SQL type syntax):

```
SELECT Item_Code, Received_Amount 
FROM Purchasing_Cube
WHERE Received_Date > = Today()-91
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.